# Why does Oracle add extra tables to my ddl export

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle-sql-data-modeler

Probably this is trivial, but I'm not sure why Oracle creates extra tables when I export my relational design as a ddl.

```
CREATE TABLE WHY
(
Col1_ID    INTEGER NOT NULL ,
Col2_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
) ;
ALTER TABLE WHY ADD CONSTRAINT WHY_PK PRIMARY KEY ( Col1_ID, Col2_ID ) ;
```

Oracle added this tables

```
CREATE TABLE WHY_JN
(JN_OPERATION CHAR(3) NOT NULL
,JN_ORACLE_USER VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
,JN_DATETIME DATE NOT NULL
,JN_NOTES VARCHAR2(240)
,JN_APPLN VARCHAR2(35)
,JN_SESSION NUMBER(38)
,Col1_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
,Col2_ID INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

and this

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER WHY_JNtrg
AFTER 
INSERT OR 
UPDATE OR 
DELETE ON WHY for each row 
Declare 
rec WHY_JN%ROWTYPE; 
blank WHY_JN%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN 
 rec := blank; 
 IF INSERTING OR UPDATING THEN 
   rec.Col1_ID := :NEW.Col1_ID; 
   rec.Col2_ID := :NEW.Col2_ID; 
   rec.JN_DATETIME := SYSDATE; 
   rec.JN_ORACLE_USER := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER'); 
   rec.JN_APPLN := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'MODULE'); 
   rec.JN_SESSION := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSIONID'); 
   IF INSERTING THEN 
     rec.JN_OPERATION := 'INS'; 
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN 
    rec.JN_OPERATION := 'UPD'; 
  END IF; 
ELSIF DELETING THEN 
  rec.Col1_ID := :OLD.Col1_ID; 
  rec.Col2_ID := :OLD.Col2_ID; 
  rec.JN_DATETIME := SYSDATE; 
  rec.JN_ORACLE_USER := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER'); 
  rec.JN_APPLN := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'MODULE'); 
  rec.JN_SESSION := SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSIONID'); 
  rec.JN_OPERATION := 'DEL'; 
END IF; 
INSERT into WHY_JN VALUES rec; 
END; 
/
```

Top of ddl file:

```
--   Generated by Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler 4.1.3.901
--   at:        2016-03-28 19:37:37 EDT
--   site:      Oracle Database 11g
--   type:      Oracle Database 11g
```

Bottom of file

```
 -- Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler Summary Report: 
 -- 
-- CREATE TABLE                            1
-- CREATE INDEX                             0
-- ALTER TABLE                             3
-- CREATE VIEW                              0
-- ALTER VIEW                               0
-- CREATE PACKAGE                           0
-- CREATE PACKAGE BODY                      0
-- CREATE PROCEDURE                         0
-- CREATE FUNCTION                          0
-- CREATE TRIGGER                           3
-- ALTER TRIGGER                            0
-- CREATE COLLECTION TYPE                   0
-- CREATE STRUCTURED TYPE                   0
-- CREATE STRUCTURED TYPE BODY              0
-- CREATE CLUSTER                           0
-- CREATE CONTEXT                           0
-- CREATE DATABASE                          0
-- CREATE DIMENSION                         0
-- CREATE DIRECTORY                         0
-- CREATE DISK GROUP                        0
-- CREATE ROLE                              0
-- CREATE ROLLBACK SEGMENT                  0
-- CREATE SEQUENCE                          0
-- CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW                 0
-- CREATE SYNONYM                           0
-- CREATE TABLESPACE                        0
-- CREATE USER                              0
-- 
-- DROP TABLESPACE                          0
-- DROP DATABASE                            0
-- 
-- REDACTION POLICY                         0
-- 
-- ORDS DROP SCHEMA                         0
-- ORDS ENABLE SCHEMA                       0
-- ORDS ENABLE OBJECT                       0
-- 
-- ERRORS                                   0
-- WARNINGS                                 0
```

I will appreciate if anyone can point me to an official reference for this.

Comment: In my experience the Oracle database would certainly not add extra tables or triggers. How were these tables created? What version of Oracle are you using? Any other products involved?

Comment: @BobJarvis I used Oracle Data Modeler first, then exported DDL file. Oracle 11g. No other product involved.

Comment: And what was in the output from Oracle Data Modeler - just the definition of the WHY table, or did it contain the other stuff as well?

Comment: OK - so this is something that a data modeling tool created, not the Oracle database itself. (You may think I'm splitting hairs - after all, it's all *Oracle* stuff - but as with most large corporations, the left hand not only doesn't know what the right hand is doing, the left hand doesn't even know *how many* right hands there are :-). I've re-tagged with Oracle Data Modeler - perhaps you'll get a better answer that way. In any case, I suspect it very much depends on what else is in your model. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It appears some setting enables tracing what happens inside table `WHY` to table `WHY_JN`. 
Cross-check your settings with the manual.